# Monitoring PCIe lane Usage

Tags: gpu, pcie

Is there a way to monitor PCIe lane bandwidth in Ubuntu 16.04? I would like to see how and if the PCIe lane max bandwidth is bottlenecking training a model in Tensorflow.

Answer (score 5):

I think you can do this with the PCM tools at https://github.com/opcm/pcm

Comment: Is there an option for AMD Ryzen Linux machines? I compiled and ran pcm and got a message that it only supports Intel machines. `Error: unsupported processor. Only Intel(R) processors are supported (Atom(R) and microarchitecture codename Nehalem/Nehalem-EP, Atom(tm), Westmere/Clarkdale, Sandy Bridge, Westmere-EP, Sandy Bridge-EP/Jaketown, Nehalem-EX, Westmere-EX, unknown, Centerton, Baytrail, Ivy Bridge, Haswell, Broadwell, Ivy Bridge-EP/EN/EX/Ivytown, Haswell-EP/EN/EX, Cherrytrail, Avoton, Skylake U/Y, Broadwell-EP/EX, Skylake-SP, Cascade Lake-SP, Broadwell-DE, Knights Landing, ...`